# Is it possible to write a Mongo query that validates a condition in each element of an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider the following documents:

```json
{
   _id: 1,
   a: [{b:true},{b:true}]
},
{
   _id: 2,
   a: [{b:false},{b:true}]
},
{
   _id: 3,
   a: [{b:true}]
}
```

I'd like to write a query that will return all of the top level documents that have an array ("a") that contain only elements matching {b : true}.  In this example, I'm expecting the first and third document to be returned, but not the second.

When writing the query like this, all 3 documents are returned..
{a : {b : true}}

Is there an operator that I'm missing?  I've reviewed quite a few of them ($all) and I'm not sure which would match best for this use case

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `$allElementsTrue` on the array `a.b`.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    "$allElementsTrue": "$a.b"
  }
})
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sgQy2aWIW3o) for your reference.